# Subroutine to open file with any random name

Tags: file, fortran

I apologize in advance because there are already posts with this kind of question, but I'm new with Fortran and I didn't understand them.
I'm trying to make a subroutine with input the filename.

I've written following code but it's not working as desired.

```
PROGRAM reading
implicit none
integer::dati,n
character::namefile

namefile=file.txt

call read(n,dati,namefile)
print*,'Number of data:',dati

END PROGRAM reading


SUBROUTINE read(n,num,namefile)
character::namefile
Integer::n
integer, intent(out)::num
open(40,file='namefile')
n=0
do              
 n=n+1
 read(40,*,end=999)
enddo

999 continue
num=n-1   
END SUBROUTINE read
```

Thanks

Comment: I know there is something that is not making sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an intrinsic called READ, and you SUBROUTINE is called READ, which also contains the intrinsic called READ.

If your subroutine used a name like SUBROUTINE My_Reader, then that is not the same as the intrinsic READ.

This should work, or be close to it.

```
PROGRAM reading
implicit none
integer           :: dati, n
character(LEN=40) :: FileName
LOGICAL           :: An_Error

FileName = 'file.txt'

call My_Reader(FileName, dati, An_Error)
IF(An_Error) THEN
  WRITE(*,*)'I had an error finding file="',FileName(1:LEN_TRIM(FileName)),'"'
ELSE
  print*,'Number of data:',dati
ENDIF

END PROGRAM reading


!=====================
SUBROUTINE My_Reader(FileName, Num, An_Error)
character, LEN=*, INTENT(IN   ) :: FileName
integer  ,        INTENT(  OUT) :: num
LOGICAL  ,        INTENT(  OUT) :: An_Error

character(LEN=256)              :: TextLine
Integer                         :: My_LUN
LOGICAL                         :: It_Exists

INQUIRE(File=FileName, EXIST=It_Exists)
IF(It_Exists) THEN
  An_Error = .FALSE.
ELSE
  An_Error = .TRUE.
  RETURN
ENDIF

OPEN(NEWUNIT=My_LUN, FILE=FileName)

num = 0
DO WHILE (.TRUE.)
  read(My_LUN,900,end=999) TextLine
900 FORMAT(A)
  num = num + 1
enddo

999 continue  
CLOSE(My_LUN)

REURN
END SUBROUTINE My_Reader
```

Comment: As there's no confusion between a subroutine called `read` and a `read` statement I don't understand your initial comments, then.

Comment: Well I guess I learned something tonight... I tend to avoid the same name, but perhaps it is because it causes me confusion

Comment: Yes - I wouldn't claim it's a good idea to call a subroutine `read`.

Answer (score 1):

The original code is confused about the use of `'` to delimit names.  There are two problems:

1)  In the following line the name of the file is not enclosed in quote marks (either `'`, or `"` will do in Fortran, but pairs must match) but should be.  So change

```
namefile=file.txt
```

to

```
namefile='file.txt'
```

2) Conversely, in this line

```
open(40,file='namefile')
```

the variable name is enclosed in quotation marks and shouldn't be.  Change it to

```
open(40,file=namefile)
```

'namefile' specifies that the name of the file is *namefile*, whereas `namefile` specifies that the name of the file is stored in the variable called *namefile*.